# Bootstrap 3 grid layout is not responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 to design a layout and using the grid classes to for the layout. Below mentioned in the code snippet I have used for the layout:

```
<div class=”container”>
  <div class=”row”>
    <div class=”col-sm-1 col-md-4 col-lg-3”>
      [ Metro Tiles content ]
    </div>
    <div class=”col-sm-11 col-md-8 col-lg-9”>
      [ Jquery Slider content ]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

When I try to open the page in tablet or mobile device or make the page small, it is not behaving responsive. The slider is not stacking below the tiles layout.

Can any one guide me to resolve the issue?

Comment: You are using `"` and not `”` in the actual code, right? Just making sure

Comment: Yes I am using the container and row classes of Bootstrap 3 within the "" and defining the details of Metro Tiles and Jquery Slider.

Comment: Make sure you don't have curly quote marks in your code. Also, not being responsive on tablets/phones is because you missed the <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Answer (score 0):

To make the tiles stack on top of the slider on a `small` device you should use:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      [ Metro Tiles content ]
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
      [ Jquery Slider content ]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine here: http://www.bootply.com/YgFqC17pgF

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-info">
      [ Metro Tiles content ]
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-11 col-md-8 col-lg-9 bg-success">
      [ Jquery Slider content ]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```